# How do I add "pull-down", aka "hotkey window" functionality to any app?

Tags: macos, window-manager, keybindings, bettertouchtool

I like to add the hotkey window functionality of iTerm to any app. I have [heard](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/kitty/issues/45) this is possible with BetterTouchTool, but I don't know how. I have seen opensource solutions like tdrop for linux, but none for macOS.

Comment: I need this feature for https://github.com/jwilm/alacritty/issues/450 too.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a couple of years, but hopefully this will be helpful to someone.
This is the way you would do it using [BTT](https://folivora.ai/), aka "[BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/)".

#### **Possible Solution**

This is the way you would do it using BTT.

Simply go to *Keyboard Shortcuts*, add a new *Trigger* under *All Apps* and assign the action *"Show / Hide Specific Application to it"*. All that's left is to set the desired application in the configuration pane that will show up.
[image: BTT config]

#### **Caveat**

The one app that has this built-in, that I know of, is also `iTerm`. There's one big difference with this implementation and the native `iTerm` implementation.

`iTerm` is more of a "drop-down", in that it functions as an overlay. The `BTT` implementation will literally show and hide the application. This means that whenever you are working with multiple *desktops*, and you trigger this shortcut, *BTT* will move you to the *desktop* where the application is.

I find this quite annoying TBH and would love to know if anyone knows how to do the same thing, but in a "drop-down" or "overlay" fashion

Comment: If my response was helpful, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. This will assist other users in quickly identifying the solution if they encounter a similar question.

Comment: I had the same question, but with the "drop-down" style requirement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75430786/kitty-terminal-hotkey-drop-down-overlay-hotkey-similar-to-iterm2-hotkey-window Maybe you can get some value out of the answers/comments